# Iframe fullscreen for responsive screen resolution and tablet portrait modality

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I wrote some code to manage responsive fullscreen iframe. It works almost well :). The problem is when there is a screen resolution like 1680x1050 (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geVk9.png)). So, in that case, I would like to move the iframe at center of screen with the same black background on top and down. Add, with the same css, I would like to do it when the iframe is in fullscreen on portrait modality on tablet.

```css
.FullScreen {
  &-target {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20000;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #0a0a0a;
  }

  &-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 40px;

    &--active {
/*....
....*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mne-contentBorder js-fullscreen-target FullScreen-target">
      <div class="myEMLObj">
      <div class="EMLObj-wrapper">
          <img class="EMLObj-placeholder" src="data:image/gif;">
          <iframe class="myObject-Iframe js-Iframe" src="" name="Iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Don't care about white rectangle in the ifame, just focus in the black background caused by screen resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geVk9.png)

[For tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgmR0.png)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. I did the upload. Thanks for help

Comment: do you want to remove the black area in all the devices desktop, tablets??

Comment: No, I don't. I added it to hide other elements behind. I used z-index to create iframe fullscreen with button.

Comment: created sample jsfiddle. Are you looking similar to this https://jsfiddle.net/7tfwhk0y/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add css for iframe

```
iframe{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have this css for the class myObject-Iframe. It works fine with a lot of screen resolution. But I found this bug for a monitor with 1680x1050 screen resolution. For example I tried to put height 100% in every div you see in the HTML and I thought it was a good solution but I deform the content of iframe. I would like to keep the ratio of iframe. So a way could be a black background behind the iframe (on <div class="mne-contentBorder js-fullscreen-target FullScreen-target">) and the iframe at center keeping ratio. Just moving a little bit down the iframe.

Comment: You want to keep the iframe ratio same through out the devices? Ex: if iframe ratio is 1:1, then it should be same in all the devices i.e 1:1 ?

Comment: Look at new pictures, please. For desktop not standard resolution I would like something like this (picture 1). Ex: if strange resolution (ex 1680x1050), change position. To create the picture I put top:50px on iframe css class. For tablet I would like something like this (picture 2). I don't know which is the right way to do this kind of 'toggle' for position. Thanks for your time